# Toolbar with Custom View not Displaying with Full Width in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I went through lots of answers here related to Toolbar but none of the answers could help me.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have an extended toolbar which will display a logo and menu items.

The way I'm trying to achieve this is through toolbar. First I create the toolbar and add my custom view.

My toolbar.xml:-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/dl_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:clipToPadding="false">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">


    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="#358c44"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#358c44"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

My name activity:-

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
     toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
   /* toolbar.setPadding(10,10,10,10);*/
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

My app show like this:-

[image]

I am new in android developing please help me! Thanks in advance

After update my code my app look like:-

[image]

Comment: Do you want to update toolbar when tab is changed?

Comment: No no i just want green line take full width of screen.

Comment: set toolbar height to android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: I tried but no sucess.

Answer (score 2):

use AppBar layout upon toolbar, see the full tutorial [here](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en)

Comment: So Design Custom ActionBar, use ImageView instead of setLogo, remeber that inside toolbar use frame layout to handle positions and etc.

Comment: But how i use menu Items.

Comment: `ImageButton` with visible actions, and custom dialog for hidden items

Comment: can you describe with example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is working for me

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        // imageView for logo
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/title" />

        // This is for search button on the right side
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/button_image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and in your activity simply set it like this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

for menu add this in your main activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuSettings:
            // Do some thing on setting press
            break;
        case R.id.menuAboutUs:
            // Do some thing on About us 
            break;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and for list of menu item add menu_main.xml file in your menu directory under your resource directory and items in this file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuSettings"
        android:title="Settings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuAboutUs"
        android:title="About Us" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Its also give spacing on menu icon size.

Answer (score 0):

check below code it worked. I used toolbar.xml file in src\main\res\layout folder.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:id="@+id/relative">
        <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarFav"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relative">
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```